# creating a reusable user control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

In the (fairly large) LOB application we are building with WPF for UI we have a lot of viewmodels that contain the same kind of data sub-object. For example, there are a lot of addresses

```
public class AddressViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

   public string City {...}
   public string ZipCode {...}
   public string Address {...}
   public string Number {...}

  // INPC logic omitted 
}
```

scattered among business objects:

```
public class CustomerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public string Name {...}
     public AddressViewModel BillingAddress {...}
     public AddressViewModel DeliveryAddress {...}
     /*
     ...
     */
}
```

is it possible to build a reusable custom User Control which we can bind to any address sub-object?

In a view (possibly another custom user control) designed to edit customer details we would like to put a custom control like this

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="OurApp.View.AddressEditor"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>

        <TextBox x:Name="ZipCode" Text="{Binding Path=ZipCode, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,19,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />

         <!-- other fields for the rest of AddressViewModel properties-->

    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

that we can simply use like this in a view bound to a CustomerViewModel instance

```xml
 <TextBox x:Name="Name" Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" />

<AddressEditor SomeProperty="{something that points to BillingAddress}" />
<AddressEditor SomeProperty="{something that points to DeliveryAddress}" />
```

What is the correct way to do this? We tried to point the binding to BillingAddress but we did not find a working way...

Thanks in advance for any contribution,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah that should be very easy, either create a lookless control with `DataTemplate`, or just create a standard UserControl. Trick it to set its `DataContext` to a full Address object

```xml
<local:AddressControl DataContext="{Binding BillingAddress}"/>
```

Which would allow your new "AddressControl" to have markup something like this

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
<Label Content="City"/>
<TextBox Content="{Binding City}"/>

<Label Content="ZipCode"/>
<TextBox Content="{Binding ZipCode}"/>

<Label Content="ZipCode"/>
<TextBox Content="{Binding ZipCode}"/>

<Label Content="Number"/>
<TextBox Content="{Binding Number}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Actually this is the same method I tried first before asking here but it did not work because in my experimental code BillingAddress and DeliveryAddress where members and not properties (my fault), I was a bit surprised I could not get WPF to work in this simple case :) Now it is working!

Comment: This is the best solution so far of all 50 pages I've searched on how to - thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can set the datacontext for your adresseditor to eg. the BillingAddress it should work as long the billingaddress has the properties you need in your usercontrol

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="Name" Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" />
<AddressEditor DataContext="{Binding Path=BillingAddress}" />
```

instead of setting the datacontext its also possible to create a dependency property for your usercontrol where you can bind your BillingAddress to.

Comment: Actually this is the same method I tried first before asking here but it did not work because in my experimental code BillingAddress and DeliveryAddress where members and not properties (my fault), I was a bit surprised I could not get WPF to work in this simple case :)